# How to add a new user in SQL Server 2012 Master Data Services if another computer with the same name exists in the same domain?

Tags: sql-server, master-data-services

While adding a new user in User and Group Permissions,I found this issue.

If the User Name and any other computer name in the same domain is same while adding a user to MDS, it adds a $ sign to the name and takes that other computer name instead of the user.